# How JavaScript closure works in this sample cases?

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-scope, self-invoking-function

I am relatively new with the Javascript closure concept.
I know how to get the work done, but I want to understand the concept through and through.

Can somebody explain in short, why example 1,2 works,and 3,4 doesn't?
Any good links regarding js closures will be appreciated as well.

**Example 1**

```
    var add = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var plus = function() {
             return ++counter;
         };

         return plus;

     })();

    console.log(add()); //1
    console.log(add()); //2
    console.log(add()); //3
```

**Example 2**

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();//1
add();//2
add();//3
```

**Example 3**

```
var add=function(){
var counter=0;
var plus=(function(){
  return ++counter;
})();
return plus;

} 
 console.log(add());//1
 console.log(add());//1
 console.log(add());//1
```

**Example 4**

```
var add=function(){
var counter=0;
var plus=(function(){
  return ++counter;
});

return plus;
}


console.log(add()());//1
console.log(add()());//1
console.log(add()());//1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/

Comment: in the example 3, the `plus` you return is not a function, but the result of the execution of the IIFE, so it's `1`. In the example 4 the `add` function is executed each time as a "new" one (it's a basic function declaration so it creates its variables each time), so that counter always start at `0` and ends up being `1` (actually exemple 3 is in the same situation too)

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, kaddath -got my answer